# Sudoku in Java. Index out of Bounds Exception

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I've got an IndexOutOfBounds exception in the following program. It consists of three files:

Important are only two of them, the GUI is working fine. Here is the first one:

```
interface SudokuObserver {
    public void modified(int i, int j);
}

public class SudokuData
{
    public int[][] feld = new int[9][9];
    public SudokuObserver obs = null;

    public SudokuData()
    {
        int i,j;
        for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<9; j++) {
                feld[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getNumber(int x, int y)
    {
        return feld[x][y];
    }

    public void setNumber(int x, int y, int v)
    {
        feld[x][y] = v;
        if (obs != null)
            obs.modified(x, y);
    }

    public void setObserver(SudokuObserver o)
    {
        obs = o;
    }
```

So the Sudoku field is allocated as a 9x9 integer array. The following file is called SudokuSolver and has an algorithm to write the possible numbers for each square into an ArrayList. Then the second algorithm works as following: He finds the square which has the minimum of possible numbers, sets the first of the numbers saved in the ArrayList on that square and does this recursive, so he starts again at defining the possible numbers for each square, taking the one with the smallest number of possibilities and picks the first one to put it into that field. A for-loop runs over the possible Numbers for each square while doing that.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SudokuSolver
{
    SudokuData data;

    public SudokuSolver(SudokuData d)
    {
        data = d;
    }


{
  /*Pseudoalgorithm:
  - Inserts the numbers 1-9 into a Collection called res
  - Looks at line x, which numbers are in there and erases them out of the      
        collection
  - Looks at column y, which numbers are in there and erases them out of the      
        collection
  - Looks in the 3x3 Square (x,y) which numbers are already in there and erases
        them out of the collection
  - Gives back the possible candidates for that field

 */
```

Here i initialize my ArrayList.

```
     public ArrayList<Integer> offen(int x, int y)
 {
 ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
         /* The collection is saved in an ArrayList */
     int k = 0;
```

Here I just fill in the numbers 1-9 in my ArrayList.

```
 for (int i=1;i<10;i++) 
     {
            res.add(i);
         }
```

Now comes the difficult part: I loop over j from zero to nine, then over k. The line is constant with the given x, the j runs over the columns, so i got every square in the given line, and in every square i check for every number from 1-9. Care: the index goes from 0-9 while the elements go from 1-9 so k has to be 0-9 cause the get()-method takes an index as input. If there is any compliance I remove the element from the ArrayList.

```
   for (int j=0;j<9;j++) 
   {
     for (k=0;k<9;k++) 
     {
       if (this.data.feld[x][j] == (res.get(k)))
        res.remove(k);
     }
```

Same stuff as above for the columns, constant column and j loops.

```
     for (k=0;k<9;k++) 
     {
       if (this.data.feld[j][y] == res.get(k))
        res.remove(k);
     }
   }
```

Now i get my inputs in two new variables, just because i had typed the code part below before with wrong variable names.

```
   int m = x;
   int n = y;
```

Here is the part for the 3x3 squares, i do this with if conditions, so this is just one of the 9 parts, I didn't want to post them all here, cause they just differ in a few constants. I check in which square my input x,y is, and then I loop over the square and check which numbers are there, which are also still in my ArrayList and remove them.

```
   if (m<=2 && n<=2) 
   {
    for (m=0;m<3;m++) 
    {
      for (n=0;n<3;n++)
      {
        for (k=0;k<9;k++)
        {
          if (this.data.feld[m][n] == res.get(k))
           res.remove(k);
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

Now I return the ArrayList

```
  return res;
    }


//findSolution() finds a Solution
public boolean findSolution()
{
    /*Possible Strategy:
    - Find the square, which has the fewest possible candidates
      - If there are more than one candidates, who have the minimum of candidates,
            take any of them
      - If there are no more open candidates, there is a solution found. Return 
            true
    - Loop over the candidates of this square and by setting the first possible 
          candidate into this square[x][y]
    - Call the method findSolution() recursive to find in dependence of the set 
          value the values for the other fields 
      If there is a blind alley, take the next possible candidate (Backtracking!)

    */
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int x = 0; // x coordinate of the field with the fewest open candidates
int y = 0; // y coordinate of the field with the fewest open candidates
int counter_offene_felder = 0;   // counts the number of open fields
int min = 9;
```

I'm looping over j and k, looking if the number of possible candidates is more than 0, that means I'm running through the whole sudoku field and count the number of open fields.

```
for (j=0;j<9;j++) 
   {
     for (k=0;k<9;k++) 
     {
        if ( this.offen(j,k).size() >= 0) 
        {
          counter_offene_felder += 1;
        }
```

If the number is < than min = 9 possible candidates, i take it as the min and save the coordinates of that field

```
        if ( (this.offen(j,k)).size() < min )
        {
          x = j;
          y = k;
        }
     }
   }
```

now i initialize and ArrayList for the field with the fewest possible candidates and put them into this ArrayList with my offen-method

```
  ArrayList<Integer> candidate_list = this.offen(x,y);
  for (k=0;k<this.offen(x,y).size();k++) 
  {  // runs over candidates
    int v = this.offen(x,y).get(k);   // takes the first candidate
    this.data.setNumber(x,y,v);   // writes the first candidate into square [x][y]
   this.findSolution();    // calls findSolution() recursive
  }

If there are no more open fields, I've found a solution

  if (counter_offene_felder == 0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else return false;
}

}
```

The problem is, that I get an IndexOutOfBounds Exception at line 39, at Index 8 Size 8. But I don't know why. :(

Comment: thats a TON of code, where is line 39?

Comment: Think it's this:            `res.remove(k);`  This decreases the size of your `ArrayList`, adjusting the position of the elements. Maybe `res.remove(res.indexOf(k));` would work.

Comment: I tried it but then I still get that error, but now it changed from 8 to -1. So it definitely is the decreased size of the ArrayList. That means I need a method with which I can remove elements without letting the ArrayList getting smaller. On the other hand, if the method you mentioned is working like that, why do I now get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException -1 error?

Comment: Which line are you getting the ArrayOutOfBoundsException on? Not just the line number, but the code as well?

Comment: you have just done a perfect work, but please share the codez related to the error, it's hard to read really, thanks

Comment: I get a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData<ArrayList.java371>
at .... at 
    SudokuSolver.offen<SudokuSolver.java41> 

This is exactly this line:
    res.remove(res.indexOf(k));

Answer (score 1):

Not positive that this is where you are getting your error... but you could run into an issue when you do something like this.

```
for (k=0;k<9;k++) 
 {
   if (this.data.feld[j][y] == res.get(k))
    res.remove(k);
 }
```

For instance, say that at k=1 the if statement evaluates to true.  Then you will remove an element from the ArrayList.  Then when k=8, and IndexOutOfBounds exception will be thrown because the ArrayList only contains 8 elements (0-7)

Assuming that no other threads will be modifying `this.data.feld[][]`, you will only ever get one match when going through this loop.. so you could do something like this...

```
int match = -1;     

for (k=0;k<res.size();k++) {
       if (this.data.feld[j][y] == res.get(k)){
        match = k;
        break;
     }
}

if(match != -1)
     res.remove(match);
```

Comment: I already tried that, but on the java docs is written the following about that method: 
 "Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element."

So what is the benefit if I change it like Saviour Self posted above, because then I first get the Index of that element and then remove it with the same method remove() Instead of using remove() directly by telling it the index.

Comment: see edit.. I think this accomplishes what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thats not the problem I guess, cause the ArrayList doesn't get smaller in the if condition. It checks if theres an element, and if there isn't get(k) delivers -1. So the condition isn't true and nothing happens. The point is: The ArrayList has to stay at the same length, like you said above.

Comment: get(k) will never return a -1 (unless you have explicitly stored a -1 in the list).  It returns the element at index k and throws an exception if the index is not valid.  You need to make sure you are not changing your arraylist while iterating over it, that is what I was trying to help you accomplish.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. Thats true, but that would not have fixed the OutOfBoundsExceptions caused be the decreasing size. I fixed it now by using the code below posted by Saviour Self, but I still got troubles with the recursive part.

Comment: Well you should not hard code the 9 into your for loop.. should be for(k=0; k < res.size(); k++). As long as you do removal ouside of the loop.. this will never throw and exception.  Let me know if there is anything else I can do.

Comment: Ah, good hint, I will remember the next time. Yes maybe, now when I start the programm, it throws a lots of errors at a method, but they are so many (due to the recursive part) that I don't see which error it is in the terminal, just like 100 lines with at .... (adress of error in the programm) . I also can't scroll up cause the whole terminal is full with it now. Any ideas? ^^ Its the same error everytime in the recursive function

Comment: Maybe stackoverflow error? You could be getting caught in an infinite recursion.. Post what you can or can you point out exactly which function is recursive?

Answer (score 0):

I think the contains() method will help eliminate your exceptions for this loop.

Try replacing your code with this:

```
for (m=0;m<3;m++) 
    {
      for (n=0;n<3;n++)
      {
        if (res.contains(this.data.field[m][n]))
            res.remove(res.indexOf(this.data.field[m][n]));
      }
}
```

It will iterate over the data.field, and check the ArrayList to see if it contains the value at m,n. If it does, it will remove it.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it, good idea, but now I get another problem, the recursive part has some kind of trouble, if I start the program it freezes for 5 secs and I get kind of hundreds of lines in the terminal which say
    at SudokuSolver.findSolution(SudokuSolver.java:223)

Line 223 is :

Comment: I think that kind-of oversteps the bounds of the question posted. What exactly is `offen`? Can you add its definition to the code?

Comment: Yes of course, offen is the method that does all the stuff, its written above when i start the second file named SudokuSolver. It creates the ArrayList, finds the possible elements for the square, given in and gives the ArrayList with the possible numbers back. But why do you need this?

Comment: I can't be certain about this, but one thing I see is this line here: `ArrayList<Integer> candidate_list = this.offen(x,y);`  You initialize this ArrayList, but you never use it. You keep calling `this.offen(x,y)` in the following lines. I think this would be a source of your problem.